# How to programmatically instantiate a Polymer element?

Tags: ajax, polymer

Is there some way to programmatically create a Polymer element that has no manifestation in the DOM, such as `<polymer-ajax>`?

I'm interested in this because doing Ajax requests via `<polymer-ajax>` is annoying in situations where you're doing something like:

1. Generate a URL
2. Retrieve URL (asynchronously)
3. Manipulate the response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can instantiate custom elements just as you can existing native HTML elements. Have you tried `var el = document.createElement('polymer-ajax');`? The only (potential) gotcha with Polymer elements is that its special features like `{{}}` bindings and `*Changed` handlers get cleaned up over time if the element is never added to the DOM.

http://www.polymer-project.org/polymer.html#bindings

Comment: it still create a DOM which kinda ugly because we didn't need it.

Comment: Can you explain what that means?